# How to be ready for the ongoing crisis?

Tags: arrowverse, suggested-order, crossovers

In *Arrowverse*, they are doing the crossover *Crisis on Infinite Earths*. I heard it's connected to a lot of shows from Arrowverse and out of Arrowverse.

So I wanted to know how much I should know before watching Crisis? Which shows I should be aware of, I am up to date with only Flash and Arrow and have seen Elseworld crossover.

Comment: Just guessing but roughly speaking I'd say the episodes are self contained. Meaning that they explain the important parts in the show, but there are definitely scenes that reference the various shows. So if you want to be aware of everything, then you probably have to watch a lot of stuff - including things like the Brandon Ruth Superman Returns movie. If you aren't as concerned at catching everything then I think just watching Flash/Arrow is fine.

Comment: @Phlegon_of_Tralles I gave it a try but  I have lot of confusions now :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After watching the crisis episodes, IMO I guess you have to **definitely watch Arrow** and maybe Flash and Supergirl.

**ARROW:** (Important to watch) 
The final season deals with the build-up to the crisis event and also throughout the season hints at

> the death of Arrow in the crisis.

It also explains more about the crisis' effects and about the Monitor and so this season of Arrow is important

**FLASH:** (Not important) 
The latest season of the Flash also deals with the prophecy that:

> The Flash WILL DIE

However, frankly there isn't much in the season about crisis that hinders your viewing. The only plot-point that aligns with the crisis is the introduction of Nash Wells who believes Monitor is a false god and unknowingly starts the crisis

**Supergirl:** (Not important for crisis. Important if you want to avoid spoilers for season 4) 
Well supergirl is the "my opinion" part since I have not watched the show after the Elseworld crossover and was going to continue it... And so I was hit with these spoilers while watching Crisis

> - Lex Luthor DIED (When was he introduced?) 
>  - Lena Luthor knows about Kara/Supergirl? And apparently she hates both the Danvers sisters 
>  - Some woman was having the Guardian shield

**Other shows:**

1. **Legends of Tomorrow**: No need (unless you want to know about the romance novel that Mick reads to the baby...) [as of the 3rd crisis episode]
2. **Batwoman**: No need [as of the 3rd crisis episode]. Basically the Supergirl-Batwoman friendship continues from the Elseworld crossover. There are some spoilers regarding:

   > Her sister? killing her parents or something?

Depends on your current Batwoman watching trend. If you started the show, might as well finish it...

3. **Black Lightning**: No need [as of the 3rd crisis episode]

## TLDR

- Arrow is necessary (For background related to the crisis)
- Supergirl is necessary if you want to avoid spoilers for season 4
- Flash and the other shows are not so necessary

Answer (score 5):

> I am up to date with only Flash and Arrow

### You should be fine.

To date only *Flash* and *Arrow* have had the Crisis as a plot point, the other shows have not featured any elements of the proposed crossover although characters from other shows are expected to feature in the crossover episodes.

At best, the pre-crossover episodes of other CW /DC shows have only featured the Nash Wells vignette at the end of the penultimate pre-crossover episodes.

Of course, the crossover itself may feature callbacks to non-crossover episodes from all shows but we'll have to wait and see on those.

Comment: Who is alice? Why superman living on asteroid? Why guardian left his shield to a girl? Who is this girl in superhero costume who do nothing? I did gave it an attempt and got so many confusion listed 30%

Comment: @AnkitSharma Sounds like separate questions, but... Batwoman's sister, who's gone a bit mad and is the season's bad guy. Cos Lois is pregnant and being on Kandor means no superpowers and the baby won't kick and kill her.Dunno who you mean. Probably Lila (chief of Argus/John Diggle's wife) who is actually Harbinger. :) Hope that helps

Comment: Ankit. All of those questions would be answered by watching all episodes of the other shows but they aren't related to the main crossover plot.

Comment: @Dave if you read question then you will know I am up to date with Arrow so I know Harbinger

Comment: @AnkitSharma I get that you do not recognize Jimmy's sister (the one he left the shield to) nor Dreamer (the girl in costume that does nothing) but they only appear for like 10 seconds at most and are not essential to understanding the plot so I don't get why that would confuse you. Alice is also just mentioned as an adversary to Batwoman, not essential to the plot of Crisis, so you can just ignore her, too. Superman is different, but you wrote in the Question that you saw last years Elseworlds - where Clark and Lois explained that they were going to move to Argo (the asteroid) and why.