# Episodic chronology of Crisis on Infinite Earths

Tags: arrowverse, chronology, crossovers

Can someone please explain to me the S*nn*E*nn* (season and episode indices) of the new *Crisis on Infinite Earths* episodes and how they fit into other DC universe serials?

I've been recording [batwoman](/questions/tagged/batwoman) and [the-flash](/questions/tagged/the-flash) for several weeks and plan to binge-watch them over a weekend (in sequence) but now I'm tasked with figuring out how *Crisis on Infinite Earths* fits into it all.

For example: At what point do I view Batwoman S01E09 (Crisis on Infinite Earths: Part Two)? Before or after Crisis on Infinite Earths S01E01?¹ Am I simply to discard the plot points of the first two in favor of the crossover series?

---

¹ <sub>I freely admit that I have been hopelessly lost in the whole multiverse concept from day one. Personally, I prefer to be interested in the fictional character's storyline and follow it through the ups and downs.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing first there is no *Crisis on Infinite Earths* S01E01? As it's not a different show but a crossover of five existing [Arrowverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrowverse) showa with some extra additions.

First *Crisis on Infinite Earths* is not limited to *The Flash* and *Batwoman* and if you don't know other shows you might end up getting confused. Also, Crisis on Infinite Earths is 5 episodes (6 if you count *Black Lightning* S03E09) but only three episodes are out yet.

Also, you need to know about the previous crossover [Elseworlds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elseworlds_(Arrowverse)) where we got to know about *Monitor* and what he wants.

It takes place after *Arrow* S08E07, *The Flash* S06E08, *Batwoman* S01E08, *Supergirl* S05E08 and  *Legends of Tomorrow* Season 4. The whole of *Arrow* S08 is used as the buildup for Crisis and *The Flash* also to an extent.

Main Crisis events in the chronology are:

1. Supergirl S05E08 (Crisis on Infinite Earths: Part One)
2. Batwoman S01E09 (Crisis on Infinite Earths: Part Two)
3. The Flash S06E08 (Crisis on Infinite Earths: Part Three)

After that *Arrow* S08E08 and *Legends of Tomorrow* will come on January 14.

Related post: [How to be ready for the ongoing crisis?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/105517/how-to-be-ready-for-the-ongoing-crisis)

Answer (score 2):

Pt1. Super Girls S05E09

Pt2. Batwoman S01E09

Pt3. The Flash S06E09

Pt4. Arrow S08E08

Pt5. Legends ot Tomorrow S05E0

You're welcome

Comment: what value it adds to the existing answer?